What does it mean that fixed effects are "balanced"?
I'm following the fixest tutorial, and in this chapter there is written:

We can see that the fixed-effects are balanced across the dimensions. Indeed, apart from the first dimension, only one coefficient per fixed-effect needs to be set as reference (i.e. fixed to 0) to avoid collinearity across the different fixed-effects dimensions. This ensures that the fixed-effects coefficients can be compared within a given fixed-effect dimension.

What does it mean that fixed effects are "balanced"?
How do they differ from "unbalanced" fixed effects?
Can you give me an example of "balanced" vs "unbalanced" fixed effects?

later on it also says they are "perfectly balanced". So I guess they could be "unperfectly balanced" as well?
